# Django Get Last Object for each Value in List

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

I have a model called `Purchase`, with two fields, `User` and `amount_spent`.

This is `models.py`:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_spent = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to get the last purchases from a list of users.
On `views.py` I have a list with some `User`'s objects, and I want to get the last purchase for each user in the list. I can't find a way of doing this in a single query, I checked the [latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) operator on [QuerySets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#ref-models-querysets), but it only returns one object.

This is `views.py`:

```
purchases = Purchase.objects.filter(user__in=list_of_users)
# purchases contains all the purchases from users, now I need to get the most recent onces for each user.
```

I now I could group the `purchases` by user and then get the most recent ones, but I was wondering it there is a way of making this as a single query to DB.

Comment: database `sqlite3` or `postgres`? and you want  latest purchased in order or latest purchased one obj?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL. I need just the lastest `Purchase` object, one per user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the `User`s with the `last_purchase_pk`s and then fetch these and adds that to these users:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

users = User.objects.annotate(
    last_purchase_pk=Subquery(
        purchase.objects.order_by('-created_at')
        .filter(user_id=OuterRef('pk'))
        .values('pk')[:1]
    )
)

purchases = {
    p.pk: p
    for p in Purchase.objects.filter(
        pk__in=[user.last_purchase_pk for user in users]
    )
}
for user in users:
    user.last_purchase = purchases.get(user.last_purchase_pk)
```

After this code snippet, the `User` objects in `users` will all have a `last_purchase` attribute that contains the last `Purchase` for that user, or `None` in case there is no such purchase.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Purchase.objects.filter(user__in=list_of_users).values("user_id", "amount_spent").order_by("-id").distinct("user_id")
```